# SQL Reporting Service 2016: "Could not load folder contents."

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2016

I'm getting the error: "Could not load folder." when I want to open the webportal (`http://<server nama>/Reports`).
Here is the error message in logfile:
Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.WebHost!reportserverwebapp!14!09/21/2020-11:25:31:: e ERROR:

```
[obxnt7ls]: OData exception occurred: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: The UTC time represented when the offset is applied must be between year 0 and 10,000.
Parameter name: offset
   at System.DateTimeOffset.ValidateDate(DateTime dateTime, TimeSpan offset)
   at System.DateTimeOffset..ctor(DateTime dateTime)
   at System.DateTimeOffset.op_Implicit(DateTime dateTime)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemFactory.PopulateCommonFields(CatalogItemDescriptor itemDescriptor, CatalogItem catalogItem)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemFactory.CreateFolderCatalogItem(CatalogItemDescriptor itemDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemFactory.Create(CatalogItemDescriptor itemDescriptor, Action`1 rsLoader)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemFactory.Create(FavoriteableCatalogItemDescriptor itemDescriptor)
   at Microsoft.ReportingServices.Portal.Repositories.CatalogItemRepository.<>c__DisplayClasse.<TraverseFolder>b__b(FavoriteableCatalogItemDescriptor i)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereSelectListIterator`2.MoveNext()
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.WhereEnumerableIterator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at Model.FolderRepository.LoadCatalogItems()
   at Model.Folder.get_CatalogItems()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```